# React Js: Accessing ref in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-ref

I have a text box with ref in one component(modalBox.js)  how can i access the value of text box on another component like(index.js) on button click

Answer (score 0):

check refForwarding in react.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `input` field in `Component1` -

```
const Component1 = props => {
  let textInput = useRef(null);

  const handleOnChange = event => {
    props.onChange(textInput)
  }

  return ( 
    <input onChange={handleOnChane} ref={textInput} /> 
  )
}
```

Now from an another component, where you want to capture the reference -

```
<Component1 onChange = {ref => console.log(ref) } />
```

Here I am just printing the ref object in the console. But you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>
    Click me
  </button>
));


const ref = React.createRef();
<MyComponent ref={ref}>Click me!</MyComponent>;
```